# I cannot get jQuery to update a DIV object's "margin-Right" property. Any ideas?

Tags: jquery, css

```
.fooBar {
        float: left;
        display:inline-block;
        height: 600px;
        margin-right: 0px;
}

$('.fooBar').click(function(){
    $(this).css('margin-right', '20px');        
});
```

I have a bunch of div objects which are floating and horizontally laid out. I have a button that is supposed to space them out further in real-time. You can see the line of jQuery I'm using.

However, it doesn't seem to work... at all. Any ideas on how to dynamically change a div's margin-right property?

EDIT: Here is the markup:

```
<div class="fooBar" style="width: 200px;" ><image src="../work/test1.jpg"></div>
<div class="fooBar" style="width: 210px;" ><image src="../work/test2.jpg"></div>
<div class="fooBar" style="width: 450px;" ><image src="../work/test3.jpg"></div>
<div class="fooBar" style="width: 610px;" ><image src="../work/test4.jpg"></div>
```

EDIT #2: Removing the extraneous 'inline-block' seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks all!

Comment: Can you post all of your code?

Comment: Where's your click event? Is it in `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Sure, updated with more specific code. It's assigned to a universal click st ate for all the .fooBar objects. Clicking any of them is supposed to space them all out by 20px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display and float styles are mutually exclusive (as far as I know) so you could start fixing it.

Comment: You should also use 'marginRight'

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling it's because of the hyphen. I think there are some pseudo-alias "magic strings" like marginRight which might work, try that instead. I have seen before and used backgroundColor when accessing with jQuery/JavaScript, whereas the CSS equivalent should be background-color.

Comment: Yes, it should be 'marginRight'

Comment: In the latest versions of jQuery, it doesn't matter if you use a hyphen in the css values: `For example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both .css('background-color') and .css('backgroundColor').` http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: +1 - it's about time they did that! I guess it wasn't clear which version of jQuery the OP was using though so it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Yeah, once I removed the inline-block, both versions work for me. Loving jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`Float` and `margin` will not work properly on elements that do not have `width` assigned.

Give `.fooBar` a `width` and it should work.

Also, remove the `display:inline-block;`

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/2fkx7/

NOTE: I used `margin-left`, as you wouldn't see a change to `margin-right` in the example... because there is nothing to the right of the element.